# run the pipeline inside the azure function

Tags: triggers, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I Have a one scenario; I am copying files within the blob from input to output folder using copy activity. Now I want to run this copy activity (ADF Pipeline) inside the azure function.

I am trying to do it using custom events(trigger).

Comment: What do you mean by custom events is it custom event trigger in ADF?

Comment: yes, Pratik Lad

Answer (score 0):

As i am understanding correct, there's a ADF-pipeline and an azure Function, that shall trigger the ADF-pipeline-run.

I'd do the triggering via this restapi-call: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/rest/api/datafactory/pipelines/create-run?view=rest-datafactory-2018-06-01&tabs=HTTP

[image]